# How to add group call using CXSetGroupCallAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, voip, pjsip, callkit

I want to add new call to active call. How to add new call in existing call as group / conference call?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do something like this

```
 let groupAction = CXSetGroupCallAction(call: callUUID, callUUIDToGroupWith: secondCallUUID)
 let transaction = CXTransaction()
 transaction.addAction(groupAction)
 let callController = CXCallController()
 callController.request(transaction) { error in         
     //completion?(error)
 }
```

After that you want to catch those requests from `CXProviderDelegate` and pass them to your voip library